# implCómo puedo implementar un sistema de trazas en springboot, con la librería logback, dinámico?

Tags: spring-boot

Tengo que implementar un sistema de trazas en springboot, con la librería logback, pero tiene que ser dinámico, es decir que sea modificable on the fly. Algo así como tomar la level de una tabla y modificar ahí y que vaya cambiando.

Saben algo de esto? Dónde podría ver algún ejemplo sencillo?

Answer (score 0):

logback permite utilizar variables MDC, que las defines en el fichero logback.xml y les asignas un valor programáticamente.

por ejemplo, puedes definir un appender en logback.xml de la siguiente manera:

```
    <appender name="example-appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%X{my-MDC-variable} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Y en la clase java:

```
MDC.put(my-MDC-variable, "Example value");
```